# There is an outputting issue with def commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: image of code]

this is the problem, def commands are like a save point, but there useless if I can't output anything so.....any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refrain from using images of code instead of code pasted as text itself. Please also review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please, don't post images of code.

Comment: OP - What is the actual issue you're facing, could you please clarify?

Comment: probably you need to go through a python tutorial like [this](https://www.learnpython.org/) or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) or [any](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm) you can find out there in google, and not use functions like this (`def` is not a command or a save point - it's a function definition).

Comment: `def` is not acommand but the start of a function definition and it's definitely not something like a savepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have never called the `continu()` function so what you want will never be printed.

Secondly, indent line 7 with line 6 to call it again.

And lastly....to make the thing work, create the `continu()` function outside `choiceone()` and then as I said at the beginning, call `continu()` after printing 'hi'